# python zipfile module: How to change the structure of zip archive created?

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I wrote the following code in order to zip *bin_file_path*:

```
 zf = zipfile.ZipFile(file_to_search, mode='w')
 zf.write(bin_file_path)
 zf.close()
```

If bin_file_path is for example: \dir1\dir2\bin_file, then when I unzip the zip file created, I get a directory named "dir1", inside another directory named "dir2" and only inside "dir2" I'll get the bin_file.

I want that the zip file created contains bin_file directly and not inside of sub_directories. Do you have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(file_to_search, mode='w')
zf.write(bin_file_path, custom_name)
zf.close()
```

where `custom_name` can be anything including `os.path.basename(bin_file_path)`.